# Parametrization of a curve 2

Tags: calculus, parametric

The exercise is to find the parametric equation this curve: $x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 3 = 0$

So, I'm feeling pretty lost here and don't really know where to start. The process is explained poorly in my book with very few examples and can't find anything really useful online. So, I would really appreciate  some help on how to tackle questions like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Observe that
$$x^2-2x-3=(x-1)^2-4.$$

The curve equation can be written as

$$(x-1)^2+y^2=4=\color {red}{2}^2.$$

The parametrisation  will be

$$x=1+\color {red}{2}\cos (t) $$
$$y=0+\color {red}{2}\sin (t) $$
with $ t\in [0,2\pi) $.

It is a circle of radius $r=\color {red}{2}$ and center $C (1,0) $.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is it

$$x=1+\color {red}{2}\cos (t) $$
$$y=0+\color {red}{2}\sin (t) $$

because the equation is equal to $ 4 = 2^2 $ ?

Comment: @gbgult Yes . you can choose an other color.